# What is the minimum distance between vertices on an integer grid with the form $(m(m+2), 0)p + (m, 1)q$?

Tags: integer-programming

Suppose, for given $m > 0$, we have a set of points of the form $v = (m(m+2), 0)p + (m, 1)q$, with $p, q, m$ integers. What is the minimum distance between two (distinct ones) of them?

Here is the square distance between any point and the origin:
$|v|^2 = (pm^2 + 2pm + qm)^2 + q^2,$

we need to find the $p, q$ that minimizes this distance given $m > 0$.

In practice it is easy enough to check a few points, and find the optimum by trial and error, but I am wondering if there is a closed form solution.

**Background:** this came up while working on this question: [How many colors is necessary so that a rectangle always covers no color more than once?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034819/how-many-colors-is-necessary-so-that-a-rectangle-always-covers-no-color-more-tha). See the second last conjecture.

(**Note:** I am not sure if there are more appropriate tags.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of minimizing the distance (which would involve a square root), we can minimize its square and deal just with integers. Let $v(p,q)$ be the squared distance:

$$v(p,q)=(pm^2 + 2pm + qm)^2 + q^2$$

Since the sum of two squares values cannot be smaller than either of them and we have $v(0,1)=m^2+1$, any smaller distance would need to satisfy two necessary conditions (remembering that we are dealing with integers and $(m+1)^2>m^2+1$):

- $|pm^2 + 2pm + qm| \leq m$, which can also be simplified as $|pm+2p+q|\leq 1$
- $|q| \leq m$ (the same reasoning applied to the second term)

Using the general inequality $|A-B|\leq |A| + |B|$ allows us to combine these two inequalities into ones: $$|p(m+2)|\leq |pm+2p+q)| + |q| \leq (m+1)$$ which immediately implies $p=0$. This simplifies our expression for the distance into $v(0,q)=q^2(m^2+1)$ and the it is clear that the smallest non-zero value occurs for $q=\pm 1$.

Thus, the smallest non-zero value of $v(p,q)$ is indeed $(m^2+1)$.

Comment: You've assumed one of the points of minimum distance is $(p,q)=(0,0)$  Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @DavidG. I'm not sure I understood your question correctly -- but the distance between the points corresponding to $(p_1,q_1)$ and $(p_2,q_2)$ is the same as the distance between points $(0,0)$ and $(p_2-p_1,q_2-q_1)$. In other words, yes, it is sufficient to consider the distances between $(0,0)$ and other points.

Comment: That was it.  I think my attempt to examine the points before I just graphed it confused me.

Answer (score 1):

A sample plot below for $m=3$.

It turns out to be the same final grid as $(p',q) \to (mq,(m+2)p'+q)$

It then turns out that the closest two points (tied with many others) are:

- $(0,0) \to (0,0)$
- $(0,1) \to (m,1)$

So the minimum distance is $\sqrt{m^2+1}$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer (I only noticed it now. I will go over the details to see if it is enough to make a proof from.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $v^2$ is a sum of squares of integers, and it's not $0$, then it must be $1$ (if we can find such a solution). There are two choices:

**Case 1:** $q=0$ and $pm^2+2pm+qm=\pm1$. I can easily guess a solution for
$pm^2+2pm=-1$: $p=1$ and $m=-1$

**Case 2:** $q=\pm 1$ and $pm^2+2pm+qm=0$. Same $p$ and $m$ as above also verify this case.

Comment: I realized now my question did not specify to find $p, q$ given $m$. I will update my question.